# Loading data from one Hive table to another with partition

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have data in one Hive table and would like to load data into another hive table.

The source table is reg_logs which has 2 partitions, date and hour. The data gets loaded into this table hourly. The schema is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reg_logs (
id int,
region_code int,
count int
)
PARTITIONED BY (utc_date STRING, utc_hour STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/ad_data/raw/reg_logs';
```

The destination table is reg_logs_org all I would like to do is copy all data from reg_logs beside utc_hour column.

Schema I created is: (please correct if I am wrong)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reg_logs_org (
id int,
region_code int,
count int
)
PARTITIONED BY (utc_date STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/ad_data/reg_logs_org';
```

Insert data into reg_logs_org from reg_logs:

```
insert overwrite table reg_logs_org
select id, region_code, sum(count), utc_date
from 
reg_logs
group by 
utc_date, id, region_code
```

error message:

```
 FAILED: SemanticException 1:23 Need to specify partition columns because the destination table is partitioned. Error encountered near token 'reg_logs_org'
```

==

```
Thank you,
Rio
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

this is because you are missing the partition info in your insert query

```
  insert overwrite table reg_logs_org PARTITION (utc_date)
  select id, region_code, sum(count), utc_date
  from 
  reg_logs
  group by 
  utc_date, id, region_code
```

Answer (score 28):

Create a copy of your table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_backup LIKE my_table;
```

Enable dynamic partitioning

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
SET hive.mapred.mode = nonstrict;
```

Copy the table

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table_backup PARTITION (ds)
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE ds = ds;
```

The where clause is needed if you use strict mode.

Answer (score 6):

In some cases you may need 
to set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=**nonstrict**
to be able to insert data into partitioned table, for example,

```
CREATE TABLE hivePartitionedTable
(
          c1    int
        , c2    int
        , c3    string
)
PARTITIONED BY (year  int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE
;
```

then this INSERT will work:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

INSERT INTO hivePartitionedTable PARTITION (year)
VALUES (1,2,'3', 1999);
```

Answer (score 3):

**It is mandatory to use partitioned column as last column while inserting the data. Hive will take the data which is there in last column.**

So based on that insert query should be:-

```
  insert overwrite table reg_logs_org PARTITION (utc_date)
  select id, region_code, sum(count), utc_date
  from 
  reg_logs
  group by 
  utc_date, id, region_code
```

From the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-DynamicPartitionInserts):

> The dynamic partition columns must be **specified last** among the columns in the SELECT statement and in the same order in which they appear in the PARTITION() clause

Comment: I can verify this. If for example you'd want to add columns based on a source table, the query should be `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE goal_table PARTITION (partition_column)
  select current_timestamp(),*
  source_table `

The other way around leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @TomRijntjes You can check out this link :- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML

Answer (score 0):

This will not work if the first partition is in the source table is empty , I mean there are no records in the first partition of source table.
In this case I suggest to insert a dummy record along with the first partition in a separate insert script and truncate that data later.